# Flask request: determine exact path, including if there is a question mark

Tags: python, http, flask, oauth, query-string

Is there a way to determine what the path was requested to the server, including if it included a question mark? The application

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request

def root():
    return Response(
        f'full_path:{request.full_path} '
        f'path:{request.path} '
        f'query_string:{request.query_string} '
        f'url:{request.url}'
    )

app = Flask('app')
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=root)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8081, debug=False)
```

always results in

`full_path:/? path:/ query_string:b'' url:http://localhost:8081/`

if requesting either

`http://localhost:8081/?`

or

`http://localhost:8081/`

This may seem unimportant in a lot of cases, but I'm making an authentication flow with multiple redirections, where the user is meant to end up at the exact same URL as they started. At the moment, I can't see a way to ensure this happens with Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the fields you have already mentioned, Values in 'environ' field might be useful in your case:

```
def root():
    return Response(
        f'raw_uri:{request.environ["RAW_URI"]} '
        f'request_uri:{request.environ["REQUEST_URI"]}'
    )
```

---

Input:

```
http://localhost:8081/?
```

Output:

```
raw_uri:/?
request_uri:/?
```

---

Input:

```
http://localhost:8081/
```

Output:

```
raw_uri:/
request_uri:/
```

Comment: **CAUTION:** `REQUEST_URI` is not available when using Gunicorn for some reason (you'll get a `KeyError`). `RAW_URI` appears to be available with both the Flask dev server and with Gunicorn.