# Show response location header, including if there is a question mark

Tags: python, http, flask, python-requests, query-string

With Python requests, how can I determine the value of the location header returned from the server? If I have the simple webserver

```py
from flask import Flask, Response, request

def root():
    return Response(headers={
        'location': 'http://some.domain.com/?'  # Note the ?
    })

app = Flask('app')
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=root)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8081, debug=False)
```

and run

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('http://localhost:8081/', allow_redirects=False)
print(response.headers['location'])
```

I see

```
http://some.domain.com/
```

*without* the question mark after the `/`

---

This is related to [Flask request: determine exact path, including if there is a question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57440598/1319998) . I was using Python requests to test an application that returned redirects, but I realised that requests was removing trailing question marks from the location header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a red-herring: requests isn't stripping the question mark from the location header. If the Flask server is changed to return what-should-be two identical headers, one `location` and one `test`

```
def root():
    return Response(headers={
        'location': 'http://some.domain.com/?',  # Note the ?
        'test':     'http://some.domain.com/?',  # Note the ?
    })
```

and we make a raw HTTP request via a socket

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8081))  

request = \
    f'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' \
    f'host:127.0.0.1\r\n' \
    f'\r\n'
sock.send(request.encode()) 
response = b''
while b'\r\n\r\n' not in response:
    response += sock.recv(4096)
sock.close()
print(response)
```

the response contains a `test` header with the `?`

```
test: http://some.domain.com/?\r\n
```

but a `location` header without the `?`

```
Location: http://some.domain.com/\r\n
```

So it's Flask (or one of the other components used in the server) that seems to be manipulating the location header returned.