# Determine exact path, including presence/absence of trailing question mark on Flask + gevent.pywsgi WSGIServer server

Tags: python, http, flask, wsgi, gevent

Is there a way to determine what the path was requested to the server, including if it included a question mark? The application

```py
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import gevent
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from flask import Flask, Response, request

def root():
    return Response(
        f'full_path:{request.full_path} '
        f'path:{request.path} '
        f'query_string:{request.query_string} '
        f'url:{request.url}'
    )

app = Flask('app')
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=root)

server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8081), app)
server.serve_forever()
```

always results in

`full_path:/? path:/ query_string:b'' url:http://localhost:8081/`

if requesting either

`http://localhost:8081/?`

or

`http://localhost:8081/`

This may seem unimportant in a lot of cases, but I'm making an authentication flow with multiple redirections, where the user is meant to end up at the exact same URL as they started. At the moment, I can't see a way to ensure this happens with Flask + gevent WSGIServer.

---

This is a similar question to [Flask request: determine exact path, including if there is a question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440598/flask-request-determine-exact-path-including-if-there-is-a-question-mark), but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57444403/1319998) doesn't seem to be applicable when the `WSGIServer` from `gevent.pywsgi` is used, since `request.environ` has neither of the keys `RAW_URI` nor `REQUEST_URI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way by defining a custom `handler_class` / `WSGIHandler` and adding `self.path` to `request.environ`

```py
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import gevent
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIHandler, WSGIServer
from flask import Flask, Response, request

def root():
    return Response(
        f'request_line_path:{request.environ["REQUEST_LINE_PATH"]}'
    )

class RequestLinePathHandler(WSGIHandler):
    def get_environ(self):
        return {
            **super().get_environ(),
            'REQUEST_LINE_PATH': self.path,
        }

app = Flask('app')
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=root)

server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8081), app, handler_class=RequestLinePathHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

so a request to `http://localhost:8081/` outputs

```
request_line_path:/
```

and a request to `http://localhost:8081/?` outputs

```
request_line_path:/?
```